# Episode of a series from the late 90's-early 2000's where an alien criminal is sentenced to live on a primitive planet and becomes Hitler

Tags: story-identification, tv

Before I get into it, I have to say I've only seen this once, and not all of it. As the title says, it was in the late 90's/early 2000's. What I do remember of it is that it involved some alien(?) criminal who had committed a very large amount of crimes having been finally caught and his sentence was to be dropped on some "primitive" planet where he could do no damage. Just before the end, he was to be shaved clean and his hair cut, but the doctor in charge of his preparation ordered the parts of his moustache just under his nose to be left alone as it was a "thing he liked to do." The criminal was then launched to a planet and as the camera pans towards his face, scenes of WWII are shown as he is revealed to be the person who would later become known as Adolf Hitler. I want to say it was an Outer Limits-like series, but at this point I just can't remember.

Comment: This is a fairly common trope in fiction. Douglas Adams had aliens accidentally dropping "A Reagan" onto Earth in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_Zaphod_Plays_It_Safe

Comment: @user156681  I also note that a similar plot was used in the 1970s version of a show called The Tomorrow People.   In "Hitler's Last secret" June 5 and June 12 1978, it  is reavealed that HItler is actually Neebor, a shape shifting alien criminal.  https://thetomorrowpeople.fandom.com/wiki/Hitler%27s_Last_Secret

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an episode of the 90’s TV show Perversions of Science ([*The Exile*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0673533/), starring Christopher John Fields as Adolf Hitler).

It was basically like the sci-fi version of the show Tales From The Crypt. Had a bunch of famous and semi-famous actors do an episode like Jason Lee, Sean Astin, Will Wheaton, Ron Pearlman and I think even William Shatner did one.

You can [watch it online on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=19BWocbpynM).

Comment: you can improve your answer with some details and a [link](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0673533/)

Comment: @user108131 - And you can improve the answer by editing that link into Havok211's answer

Comment: THANK YOU, it's been driving me barmy for years now, and I knew I hadn't dreamed it.